# How to set image to SWT. Group

Tags: swt, composite

[image]

I have a group in SWT composite.I want to set an image to it,instead of a text.How can I achieve this?I am not finding any direct way of setting an image to that .But is there any workaround for this?

Below is the snippet

```
    final Group defineInteractionGroup = new Group(sashForm, SWT.NONE);
    Image image = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), "C:/myIcon.png");

    GridData interactionsGroupGridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
    interactionsGroupGridData.heightHint = 0;
    defineInteractionGroup.setLayoutData(interactionsGroupGridData);
    defineInteractionGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));
    defineInteractionGroup
            .setText(ResourceAssistant.getString(InteractionExpandedComposite.class, "defineInteraction"));
```

Comment: Group doesn't support images.

Comment: What would that look like? Can you create a mockup to show what you want to achieve?

Comment: I was not able to add an image as a comment so I have provided one answer and attached my mock up.